# Scrape all h2 tags from list of pages and text under each h2 tag (p and ul tags) separately and output in tabular format using python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape fault codes for cars. There are like multiple pages and each page has same h2 tags structure. I want to have output in tabular format where each h2 tag is column and extracted text from each page is a row. I have tried for page it  worked but how do i scrape for multiple pages and out put in below format

| h1 | h2 |
| --- | --- |
| p and ul tags text from page1 | p and ul tags text from page1 |
| p and ul tags text from page2 | p and ul tags text from page2 |
| p and ul tags text from page3 | p and ul tags text from page3 |
| p and ul tags text from page4 | p and ul tags text from page4 |

```python
url = "https://www.somelink.com/page1
driver.get(url)
soup_subpage = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
for i in soup_subpage.find_all('div', class_='col-md-8'):
    h2s = i.find_all(['h2'])
    h2s = [i.text.strip() for i in h2s]
    text = i.find_all(['p','ul'])
    text = [i.text.strip() for i in text]
data = dict(zip(h2s,text))
df = pd.DataFrame([data]. columns = data.keys()}



enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a loop:

```
df_list = []
for page in range(1,10):
    url = "https://www.somelink.com/page%s" %page
    driver.get(url)
    soup_subpage = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
    for i in soup_subpage.find_all('div', class_='col-md-8'):
        h2s = i.find_all(['h2'])
        h2s = [i.text.strip() for i in h2s]
        text = i.find_all(['p','ul'])
        text = [i.text.strip() for i in text]
    data = dict(zip(h2s,text))
    df = pd.DataFrame([data]. columns = data.keys()}
    df_list.append(df)
    
result = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: I tried it it just keep on adding columns so out put is like one row and for each page it added new columns while i need a new row for each page with same number of columns

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: try the edit I made above

Comment: ok, and what do you want the output to be for these 3 examples?

Comment: the above code didn't work either - since H2 tags are same in each page (like code definition, what code means, what causes the code etc) these should be the column headers . then code should go through each page and scrape text and put it under each h2 tags this completes one row - then reads second page and extracts text and put in under each corresponding h2 and this will be row-2 and so on